# Error while trying to get dictionary to pandas dataframe, python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I got "Pandas ValueError Arrays Must be All Same Length"
Before I start, I checked answers to similar problems and folks suggest to use something like:

```
DataFrame(dict([ (k,Series(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems() ]))
```

if you have only two values in dictionary or,

```
a = {'Links' : lines ,'Titles' : titles , 'Singers': finalsingers , 'Albums':finalalbums , 'Years' : years}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df.transpose()
```

But neither of them worked for me. What my code does is, goes to file in directory, captures the name and last_modified time, opens the file and use it in function called phash and returns a value. I think there could be a problem with phash function, maybe sometimes it returns a null value.

So in my case data is something like this:

```
raw_data = {}
hash_11 = []
time_1 = []
file_name_1 = []
for file in date_file_list:
    try:
        #print(file[1])
        y = file[1]
        file_name = os.path.basename(y) # extract just the filename or #file_name = os.path.split(file[1])
        file_name = file_name.split('_-_')[0]
        file_name_1.append(file_name)
        #print(file_name)
        # convert date tuple to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format
        #file_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", file[0])
        time = file[0]
        time_1.append(time)
        img = Image.open(str(file[1]))
        hash_1 = imagehash.dhash(img) 
        hash_11.append(hash_1)
        #hash_1 = str(hash_1)
        #data = [hash_1, time, file_name]
        #hamming_list.append(data)
        #print(file_name, hash_1, file_date)
        data ={'hash_1': hash_11,'time': time_1, 'file_name': file_name_1}
        raw_data.update(data)
    except:
         pass

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['hash_1', 'time','file_name'])
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what is happening here without the actual input data. Did you check the structure of `raw_data`? Do all entries really have the same length? Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Before *Dataframe* call, check length of *hash_11*, *time_1*, and *file_name_1* lists. Are they the same?

Comment: I think they should all be the same,  maybe I should add something like if else  before appending?

Comment: Yes sometimes it can not get output from phash function. In that case what should I do ?